# Как запретить поворот экрана на Android C#

Tags: c#

Как запретить поворот экрана на Android C#? 
И если можно, то написать еще подключаемые библиотеки. Спасибо

Comment: Разве оно не в манифесте запрещается?

Comment: Это AndroidManifest.xml?
Если да , то какой код вводить, чтоб все было вертикально ?

Comment: Ну это ж xamarin, а значит все выставляется через атрибуты и manifest.xml он генерируется. Вам сюда https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.ActivityAttribute/ и смотрите в определении атрибута ScreenOrientation

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо за ссылку, но там про саму ориентацию ничего не описано, там только дан синтаксис. Не могли бы вы разжевать?)

Comment: Все активити, сервисы и так далее описываются в манифесте. xamarin сам его генерирует из аттрибутов в коде. Значит вам нужно читать про значения в манифесте. На примере в ссылке видно что ScreenOrientation  генерится в android:screenOrientation. А дальше просто посмотреть что значит android:screenOrientation тут https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Activity классе Android проекта допишите в атрибуте доступную ориентацию экрана

```
[Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Attribute.ScreenOrientation/